# Hypothetical web dictionary architecture

Tags: php, mysql, dictionary, architecture

Let's say I am building a simple dictionary where users type a word and see a definition.

In an oversimplification, are there any problems with setting up my dictionary as a MySQL table, and each user request for a word will call a PHP script to find the word, and display its definition?

What's the optimal way to build this to minimize user lag time/not overheat the server? How does dictionary.com do it? My resources are limited, so I can't afford a dedicated server

Comment: Indexes. Yeah, I thought about being sarcastic about it, but I can't be bothered. So, indexes.

Comment: Unless you've more words that your native language has, it won't be that heavy on database, provided you use correct and carfull indexing. You can use full text research for better results (since, once cached, it will retrieve based on relevance)

Comment: Look into [Postgres' full text search](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.0/static/textsearch.html) functionality too. It's extremely powerful.

Answer (score 0):

As this question is tagged as architecture, so trying to provide a basic architecture overview in this case.
Problem statement consists of following points.

1. Online application - So single service/application will provide services to multiple users.
2. Text search - Most of the time queries are not complete word which could be find in database.
3. Frequent database queries - As the number of user grows this might become problem.

So, you might think of following solutions.

Google the text searching tools/library. You will find lots of them. To have some relevant search results. Or you can use how [wordweb](http://wordweb) does.

To avoid frequent database queries you can cached last 1000 results or some configurable number of results in some file such as [Lucene Search](https://lucene.apache.org/core/) does.

**DISCLAIMER**

Above architecture will hold good if there are simultaneously multiple users. Or if this is even needed. Otherwise this might be more than effort required.

Best way to develop an architecture is to make system adaptable to change. So start with basic work and keep adapting to changes.